# MDL upgrade all dynamic list elements on each tab

Tags: javascript, html, material-design, material-design-lite

I have 4 mdl tabs where I dynamically create a list of mdl cards in each one. Each card has a mdl-menu created like this:

```
// job settings dropdown :
settingsButton.setAttribute('id', 'jobSettings');
var jobUl = document.createElement('ul');
jobUl.className = 'mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect';
jobUl.setAttribute('for', 'jobSettings');
var jobLi = document.createElement('li');
var jobLi2 = document.createElement('li');
var jobLi3 = document.createElement('li');
jobLi.className = 'mdl-menu__item';
jobLi2.className = 'mdl-menu__item';
jobLi3.className = 'mdl-menu__item';
jobLi.textContent = 'Edit';
jobLi2.textContent = 'Delete';
jobLi3.textContent = 'Pay';
jobUl.appendChild(jobLi);
jobUl.appendChild(jobLi2);
jobUl.appendChild(jobLi3);
```

Which would show up in html something like this:

```
<ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
    for="demo-menu-lower-right">
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Edit</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Delete</li>
  <li class="mdl-menu__item">Pay</li>
```

Then I do `componentHandler.upgradeDom();` hoping to upgrade the mdl-menu items in each unordered list (ul).

This only seems to work for ONE list element (li) in the entire website. it doesn't work for any other element on any other tab.
How do I make my mdl-menu work on each dynamically created list element in each dynamically created ul?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue could be that you are duplicating the `id` value across multiple menu elements (MDL will get confused if there is more than one button with an `id` value that matches the `for` value on your menu element). You could add a numerical increment to your `id` and `for` values to ensure that each menu is uniquely identified. See the following example.

```js
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
const addCard = (n) => {
  const card = document.createElement('div');
  const menu = document.createElement('div');
  const button = document.createElement('button');
  const icon = document.createElement('i');
  const ul = document.createElement('ul');
  card.className = 'mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp';
  menu.className = 'mdl-card__menu';
  button.id = `menu${n}`;
  button.className = 'mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon';
  icon.className = 'material-icons';
  icon.textContent = 'more_vert';
  ul.className = 'mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect';
  ul.setAttribute('for', `menu${n}`);
  fragment.appendChild(card);
  card.appendChild(menu);
  menu.appendChild(button);
  button.appendChild(icon);
  menu.appendChild(ul);
  for (const action of ['Action 1', 'Action 2', 'Action 3']) {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = action;
    li.className = 'mdl-menu__item';
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }
};

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  addCard(i);
}

document.querySelector('#container').appendChild(fragment);
componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

```css
.mdl-card {
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Material Design Lite Cards / Menus</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>    
    <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: that did it, the ids were the same. thanks! im pulling the data from google firestore so i just changed the id to the current document id. since every card represents a document and every document has different id, each element got a different id!